# Plotting polygons as separate plots using Python

Tags: python, shapefile, polygon, plot

I have a shapefile with several polygons in a geodataframe. I want to plot each individual polygon in their own plot.

I tried

```py
for pol in z3:
  plt.figure()
  plt.plot(pol)
  plt.show()
```

But this just loops through the columns of the data frame.

Comment: What do you mean by "individual plots"? One plot including polygon subplots or separate images?

Comment: I mean separate images, as in one plot for each polygon

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

gdf = gpd.read_file("path/to/shapefile.shp")

for row in gdf.iterrows():    
    geom = gpd.GeoSeries(row[1].geometry)
    geom.plot()
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 12):

You can defined a plotting function and then call it on your [`GeoDataFrame`](https://geopandas.org/reference/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.html?highlight=geodataframe#geopandas.GeoDataFrame).

Let's dive into an example.

Here are 4 polygons in a [Shapefile](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000280.shtml) (drawn with ♥ in [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/)):

[image: QGIS polygons]

First do some imports:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Load shapefile with geopandas
poly_gdf = gpd.read_file('polygons.shp')
```

Then, define a plotting function:

```py
def plot_poly_gdf(polygon):
    p = gpd.GeoSeries(poly['geometry'])
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,10))
    ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=14)
    ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=14)
    p.plot(color='skyblue', alpha=0.6, ax=ax)
    plt.xlabel(poly['name'], fontsize=20)
    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.grid()
```

And finally iterate over your [`GeoDataFrame`](https://geopandas.org/reference/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.html?highlight=geodataframe#geopandas.GeoDataFrame), calling the previously defined function on each feature:

```py
for i, poly in poly_gdf.iterrows():
    plot_poly_gdf(poly)
```

Results:
[image: Results]

Feel more creative than I did on your plotting ;)

Answer (score 10):

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

gdf = gpd.read_file("path/to/shapefile.shp")

for row in gdf.iterrows():
    plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
    plt.axis('equal')
    x, y = row[1].geometry.exterior.xy
    plt.plot(x, y)
```

This script plots polygon's boundary.

Shapefile:

[image]

Separate Plots:

[image]

[image]